# Regarding nomenclature of a vector related to field automorphisms

Tags: field-theory

Is there a particular designation in use for the following type of vector, constructed by taking a collection of basis elements $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$, $\dotsc$, $\beta_n$ for a field extension, selecting an automorphism $\sigma$ of this extension, and evaluating it at the aforementioned basis elements term by term, namely, $(\sigma(\beta_1),\sigma(\beta_2),\dotsc,\sigma(\beta_n))$?

Comment: So, you mean given a field $k$ and extension field $K$, treated as a vector space, given a basis if $K$ over $k$, and an automorphism of $K$ which fixes $k$, what is the new basis under the automorphism called?

Comment: Yes, or more specifically, I'd like to know whether this vector of "basis transformations" has its own name.